# Joomla! Need to make linkable banner images with Camera Slideshow

Tags: php, joomla, slider

Need to make linkable images with Camera Slideshow. url must be received from Url_A in material.

in **_item.php**

```
<div class="camera-item" data-src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>">
```

I tried to do

```
<?php $urls = json_decode($item->urls); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $urls->urla;?>">
<div class="camera-item" data-src="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro); ?>">
</div></a>
```

but got error. Help to novice please! and sorry for bad english :)

**21.08**
Full code of **_item.php** with some changes

```
    <?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$images = json_decode($item->images);
$urls = json_decode($item->urls);
$slider_img = htmlspecialchars($images->image_intro);
?>


<div class="camera-item" rel="<?php echo $urls->urla;?>" data-src="<? echo $slider_img; ?>">

    <?php if ($params->get('show_caption')): ?>
        <div class="camera_caption <?php echo $params->get('captionEffect'); ?>">
            <?php $item_heading = $params->get('item_heading', 'h4'); ?>
            <?php if ($params->get('item_title')) : ?>

                <<?php echo $item_heading; ?> class="slide-title<?php echo $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>">
                <?php if ($params->get('link_titles') && $item->link != '') : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $item->link;?>">
                        <?php echo $item->title;?></a>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php echo $item->title; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                </<?php echo $item_heading; ?>>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (!$params->get('intro_only')) :
                echo $item->afterDisplayTitle;
            endif; ?>

            <?php echo $item->beforeDisplayContent; ?>


            <?php echo $item->introtext; ?>

            <?php if (isset($item->link) && $item->readmore != 0 && $params->get('readmore')) :
                echo '<a class="readmore" href="'.$item->link.'">'.$item->linkText.'</a>';
            endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

I got url to atribute rel but still can't make clickable images :(
In firebug

```
<div id="camera-slideshow" class="camera_wrap" style="height: 755px;">
<div class="camera_fakehover">
<div class="camera_src camerastarted camerasliding">
<div class="camera-item" data-src="images/slide1.jpg" rel="/index.php/urla"> </div>
<div class="camera-item" data-src="images/slide2.jpg" rel="/index.php/urla"> </div>
<div class="camera-item" data-src="images/slide3.jpg" rel=""> </div>
</div>
```

source code

```
<div class="camera-item" rel="/index.php/urla" data-src="images/slide1.jpg">

            <div class="camera_caption fadeIn">

            <div class="txt1">some text</div>
<div class="txt2">some text</div>   
                    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: And what error did you receive?

Comment: Please do `var_dump()` for ` $images->image_intro` and  and `$urls->urla`.

Comment: i got white window with 1 string at code '<div id="camera-slideshow" class="camera_wrap" style="height: 755px;">'

Comment: Turn error reporting to Developer (in global configuration server tab). Also paste the code that is right after that div in your layout.